# How to know if a Xamarin ListView is focused

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I'm looking for a way to know if a Xamarin ListView has been focused, its property IsFocused and Focus event seems not working.

In the Android project, when ListView is focused, the property CurrentFocus in the MainActivity contains an Android.Views.ViewGroup object but I don't know how to get Xamarin.Forms.ListView object from it

Is somebody able to help me ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: in touch based apps focus usually means that the element can receive keyboard input - this doesn't really make sense for a ListView

Comment: You could try to use `ItemTapped` or "ItemSelected" event to simulate the focused.

Comment: @Jason: I'm writing an app for a device with barcode scanner, hardware keyboard and Android - this really make sense to have ListView focus management

Comment: @Wendy Zang - MSFT  - Thanks, I already did it, but if the list is empty the event isn't raised and if there are few items, the user has to tap on the items instead of the ListView  area

Comment: @Sato If the empty space is not necessary, you could remove it. Then `ItemTapped` or `ItemSelected` event works well. Keep on searching, if i have something new, feedback ASAP.